# Controlling an array according to its elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

```
state = {
        squares: Array(20).fill(null)
}
```

I have this state and when I click on a random square, the array starts to fill the value.

I want to control if my all elements in the array is not null.

```
const squares = this.state.squares.slice();
squares.forEach(square => square ? console.log(true) : console.log(false))
this.setState({ squares: squares })
```

I do this and when I start clicking the squares, my console shows respectively true and false. After I clicked on all of the squares, it shows only true. However, I want to see just false until I click on all of the squares.

I tried using for method but it didn't work though.

```
for (let i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
     if (squares[i] !== null) {
          console.log(true)
     } else {
          console.log(false)
     }
}
```

These are also what I tried

```
 squares.forEach(square => square !== null ? console.log(true) : console.log(false))
```

and

```
if (squares.includes(null) === -1) {
    console.log(true)
}
```

How can I get a solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) or [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
console.log(squares.every(sq => sq !== null))
// or
console.log(!squares.some(sq => sq === null))
```